# Extract aspx pages from precompiled asp.net web site

Tags: asp.net, precompiled

Is it in any way possible to go from a pre-compiled asp.net site and back to something resembling the original code (with markup that I can update in aspx and ascx files). I have lost the original code and is left with the precompiled version of the pages. It is possible to disassemble the dlls but the code is very hard to figure out and I get many different error messages, when I try to update and rebuild the dlls that contains the precompiled aspx and ascx pages.

Answer (score 4):

[Reflector](http://reflector.red-gate.com/download.aspx?TreatAsUpdate=1) is your friend, or [ildasm.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7dy01k1.aspx) if you know how to read MSIL. And next time use a [VCS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_control) to put this code under source control to avoid uncomfortable situations like this.

Comment: It also won't be free for much longer :(  For an alternative, try ILSpy or keep your eyes open for Jetbrains' standalone decompiler.

Comment: @Sir Crispalot, yeah Red Gate will start charging for Reflector. 35 worthy bucks. I mean, I don't defend Red Gate at all for their decision but its their product and they have the right to do whatever they want with it. Personally I would spend the bucks as I can't breathe without Reflector (and without beer).